# Inspect `mysqli::errno` after UPDATE query to decide if trigger FATAL error or WARNING

Tags: php, mysqli

After an UPDATE query with `mysql::query()` I can check the `mysqli::error` or `mysqli::errno`to get the error message or number.

This is useful to log the error, but I should decide based on the severity of the error what to do.

- If it is a logic error (row does not exist, values are not valid) I should abort execution.
- If the data base was not reachable, or something similar I should just log the error but not halt the program execution.

  1. I can inspect the error number, for example error 1054 is returned when a column is unknown. The problem is mysql manual lists near 1000 errors, so check which ones are relevant seems no the way to go and can be very risky if I miss just one error condition relevant to the problem.
  2. Other problem is when the row is not in the table since no error is returned.

What is the common approach to check this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first outline your own expectation and then you ask what's common. I would say that it's common to have is, that if a database layer fails to connect to the database, to throw a database exception. So it's clear that on some system level something failed.

An application that has been written to interact with a database should then decide on it's own how to deal with these database exceptions. Normally code that expects a database to work can't work if there is none.

Now to the cases you call a logic error. That depends a lot. I won't concentrate on specific database error code (that even might change over time, new ones are added with new versions, old ones might not be used any longer). Instead concentrate whether or not the return data of some operation matches your expectation and provide such values in case you don't do so far.

For example: If an update is crucial, and you need to verify if the update was successful, well check that. But it's not part of the database layer to decide whether it was crucial or not. That's part of your application code, e.g. the *domain model* or the *transaction script*.

Mysqli itself can already throw some exceptions under circumstances, there is one exception with the extension:

```
class mysqli_sql_exception extends RuntimeException
```

For connection errors you would need to throw your own exceptions. So checking for return values and then throw your database exception.

Comment: The problem being (for UPDATES at least) `mysqli::query()` just return TRUE or FALSE. Any further error checking depends on `mysqli::errno`. The manual (http://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) does not specify any exceptions being thrown. I would like to know if the error is a programmers fault, or a servers problem. Should I check it myself before doing the query?

Comment: What do you mean by programmers error? The function will return `FALSE ` on failure and `TRUE` or the result identifier on success. What do you want to test for with an update for example specifically?

Comment: I want to know if the program is working wrong. Let´s say I'm trying to update a column no longer exists, or a row not in the DB. This is a situation that should not happen so I should check the code. It would be helpful if the system just takes a different path in this situation or if a non programmers error happen (Disk is full, DB is not accessible, etc.).

Comment: That is a classic concurrency issue. The business code needs to check first if the store still has the object that it want's to update and then update it, otherwise give an error. You can not solve that in the database client itself. You might want to lock specific objects as well (which is more compex compared to just check). So your code itself is responsible for the logic, not the database layer. Don't mix the two, otherwise you're making things more complex than they need to be.

Comment: Thanks, I know I was taking a bad approach just because what you say, things where becoming complex!.

Comment: Sure, you should outline a bit more how you structure your code. It's probably possible to make the database layer a class of it's own with the methods needed the rest of the application can deal with. Additionally you can create a row abstraction that works with any table so that you can make your business logic even more modular.